# Who starts the daily scrum meeting?

Tags: scrum, agile, meetings, daily-scrum, scrum-ceremonies

Is the scrum meeting started by the person whom comes to the meeting last

or

Anybody chosen by the team starts the scrum meeting?

Tried to find answer to this question but no luck till now

Comment: Scrum master is not mandatory to attend though he/she ensures that meeting happens. So I feel scrum master pointing someone to start the meeting will not be best answer. But I am not sure. Just a guess.

Comment: I _believe_ Scrum framework does not define who should start the meeting exactly to give the _freedom_ to each team to find the best approach for each case. With that said, will be very hard to find a canonical answer for this question.

Answer (score 4):

The team should decide. The meeting belongs to the team.

If the issue of starting off is a persistent problem during the sprint, then the SM should bring it up during the retro and facilitate the discussion to come to an agreement.

Answer (score 2):

The Scrum Master should coach the team to be self-managing so that they decide and find a way of handling this themselves i.e. if they want to have a specific person, a specific scenario e.g. last joiner or they ask the Scrum Master to nominate someone every day, its totally up to the team.

If the team repeatedly don't start the standup and they just stand around chatting then the Scrum Master needs to coach them by addressing this in workshops and retrospectives and one on ones to make sure they understand what the standup is for and why its important to kick if off on time and time-box it to 15 minutes.

Please bare in mind that a Scrum Master is not mandatory at stand-ups, mature teams don't need their scrum master at every standup and they might focus on a second team or another problem and not attend.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no special meaning to who goes first and who goes after, team members should volunteer. If multiple team members volunteer it should take seconds to sort it out because it does not really matter.

If nobody volunteers you need to speak with your team about their commitment to this project and team. It is in their own self interest that someone starts the meeting on time.

Answer (score 0):

The quesion looks the same with PSMI exam, one of my colleagues showed to me last month and got consultant from me. Some ideas for you, the practice base on my experience, you should consider the team's maturity to choose a appropriate way:

1. If you want to encourage your team member join the daily meeting on time, the meeting could start by person whom comes to the meeting last.
2. If your team use token as sign, who own token will start first.
3. Or Scrum master decide who will start (No recomend).

Please share your ideas, I think we have no answer for the type of question, just best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Once everyone arrives – and they should be reminded to always show up on time – "just flip a coin, or roll a couple of dice."  Or, if someone feels that they have a point that needs to be brought up early and wants to go first, let them.

Answer (score 0):

nvoigt, I think there *can be* a meaning to whom starts first or make the daily scrum more effective depending on the state of the project. Some advise I can give to decide on a methodology goes as follows:

- Everyone should start at least once every certain time
- The order should be beneficial for the current state of the project (for example, it might make sense to naturally allow individuals working on close tasks to report one after the other to understand the big picture)
- When working on a “Crysis” or very “important” issues, it might be wise to allow those individuals to go first, so that the following individuals know if there’s any change they have to make to their activities during the day, this also allows the team to focus on getting done what is crucial at this point in time
- Important to the previous point: everyone should take *important* / *critical* tasks once in a while depending on circumstances
- I agree that the team should feel safe about being the first to do the daily scrum, so perhaps when whom starts is not important, you can try a random way to select who starts